# Corresponding analogy for local compactness in algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In algebraic geometry, completeness is seen as an analog of compactness. What is the corresponding analog for local compactness?

Comment: When you say 'analogue of compactness', I take this to mean that for a complex variety $X$, the variety $X$ is complete if and only if the associated analytic space $X^{\operatorname{an}}$ is compact. If you then try to find a notion that corresponds to local compactness, you're going to get the empty condition: every complex analytic variety is locally compact (I think you don't need smoothness or separatedness or anything). Or do you want your analogy to take place in some different setting?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. One dumb analogue is "complete, minus a point."

Comment: in real algebraic geometry, the analog of compactness is usually closedness+boundedness...

Comment: In a complex variety, among constructible subsets (of the Zariski topology), the locally compact ones (in the ordinary topology) are the locally closed (in the Zariski topology) ones (that is, those $F\cap U$ with $F$ Zariski-closed and $U$ Zariski-open). For instance, $\{(x,y):x\neq 0 \mbox{ or }y=0\}$ is not locally closed and the corresponding set of complex points is not locally compact.

Comment: Qiaochu, that's a really disturbed answer, for which you should be proud.

Comment: I'd say *locally of finite type*, if anything. But I probably don't understand the spirit of the question.